# THREE.js planeGeometry clipped inside the walls

Tags: three.js

I want to make a 3D building using Three.js. For example, I made 6 walls and a floor by checkerboard texture. I used clippingPlanes for wall1 and wall4:

```
floor1.material.clippingPlanes = [plane1,plane4];
```

[image]

I made my planes(plane1 and plane4) by my walls(wall1 and wall4). For example, my wall4 planeGeometry and plane4 code is here:

```js
var wallGeometry4 = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(40, Floor_Height, 1, 1);
                var wall4 = createMesh(wallGeometry4, "brick_diffuse.jpg", THREE.DoubleSide, 1024, 1024);
                unit1.add(wall4);
                wall4.position.x = -10;
                wall4.position.y = 0;
                wall4.position.z = -20;
                wall4.rotation.y = 1.5 * Math.PI;
                wall4.add(new THREE.EdgesHelper(wall4, 0x000000));

                var plane4 = new THREE.Plane();
                var normal4 = new THREE.Vector3();
                var point4 = new THREE.Vector3();

                normal4.set(0, 0, -1).applyQuaternion(wall4.quaternion);

                point4.copy(wall4.position);

                plane4.setFromNormalAndCoplanarPoint(normal4, point4);
```

But I see an empty area between wall5 and wall6, because plane4(that used for clipping the floor) isn't the same size of wall4. I think Plane4 is  whole of the scene. How to change size of my plane to clip correctly? Or Is there any way to make floor bounded in walls?

Comment: `THREE.Plane()` is a math plane that is infinite.

Comment: What should I do? How can I fill the floor correctly? Isn't any way?

Comment: As an option: you know dimensions of your walls, thus you can obtain points of corners, then build a shape geometry from them.

Comment: Another option: Use intersection clipping to notch-out your corner. https://threejs.org/examples/?q=clipping#webgl_clipping_intersection

Comment: Yet another option would be yo not use clippingPlanes and write your own clipping in a quick `shaderMaterial`

Answer (score 2):

One way to achieve this as suggested is to use ShapeGeometry.

When you are creating your walls you can save the x and z co-ordinate of their starting and ending points in an array to form a loop of points of Vector2. Then you can create a new custom shape from these points using shapeGeometry.

```
points = [{x:0,y:0},{x:0,y:10},{x:10,y:10},{x:10,y:0},{x:0,y:0}]

function getShapeFromPoints(points){
    const shape = new THREE.Shape();
    shape.moveTo(points[0].x, points[0].y);
    for (let i = 1; i < points.length; i++) {
        shape.lineTo(points[i].x, points[i].y);
    }
    return shape;
}

function createPlaneFromPoints(points) {
    const planeMaterial = getPlaneMaterial();
    const shape = getShapeFromPoints(points);
    const geometry = new THREE.ShapeBufferGeometry(shape);
    geometry.rotateX(degreeToRadians(-90));
    const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, planeMaterial);
    return mesh;
}
```

Hope that helps you!